# From react-admin v3 to v4

Tags: react-admin

I am new to react-admin, and i'd like to implement custom forms for related records.
I found [this](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/AdvancedTutorials.html#custom-forms-and-ui-for-related-records) on the doc but the code doesn't seem to work for version 4 anymore.

I'd like to do the same. Open a modal for the related record.

Is there any v4 example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React-admin v4 has built-in support for related record creation, see the [Creating new choices](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/SelectInput.html#creating-new-choices) documentation.

```
import { SelectInput, Create, SimpleForm, TextInput } from 'react-admin';

const PostCreate = () => {
    const categories = [
        { name: 'Tech', id: 'tech' },
        { name: 'Lifestyle', id: 'lifestyle' },
    ];
    return (
        <Create>
            <SimpleForm>
                <TextInput source="title" />
                <SelectInput
                    onCreate={() => {
                        const newCategoryName = prompt('Enter a new category');
                        const newCategory = { id: newCategoryName.toLowerCase(), name: newCategoryName };
                        categories.push(newCategory);
                        return newCategory;
                    }}
                    source="category"
                    choices={categories}
                />
            </SimpleForm>
        </Create>
    );
}
```